# Why OpenCV face detection recognition the faces for untrained face?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0, face-detection, face-recognition, opencv3.1

I trained 472 unique images for a person A for Face Recognition using "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml".
While I am trying to detect face for the same person A for the same images which I have trained getting 20% to 80% confidence, that's fine for me.

But, I am also getting 20% to 80% confidence for person B which I have not included in training the images. Why its happening for person B while I am doing face detection?

I am using python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.2.0-dev version.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Haar-cascade Detection is used for detecting objects with the same set of features. ´

Even though **face B** is different from **face A** they share the same features; two eyes, a nose and a mouth, and therefore is the confidence for A and B the same. Using only Haar Cascades is not enough for the task of distinguishing different faces.

I recommend reading the original paper by [Viola-Jones](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

i guess here in your problem you are not actually referring to detection ,but recognition ,you must know the difference between these two things: 
1-detection does not distinguish between persons, it just detects the facial shape of a person based on the haarcascade previously trained
2-recognition is the case where u first detect a person ,then try to distinguish that person from your cropped and aligned database of pics,i suggest you follow the philipp wagner tutorial for that matter.